# Python: Create a file with a list of max values from multiple files

Tags: python, file, max

I have several files in a directory, consisting of the same size column of numbers in each file. Let's say 5 numbers. The new file I want to create using Python should also be a column of 5 numbers, but each number in this file is the maximum value in it's position from all the other files.

So, to demonstrate this, consider 3 files I have, which consists of 5 numbers as mentioned.

File 1: Column(1 2 3 4 5)
File 2: Column(7 3 8 1 5)
File 3: Column(2 3 6 8 3)

Then,

New File: Column(7 3 8 8 5)

Thanks

Comment: Did you forget to post the code you're having trouble with?

Comment: Nope. I haven't got any code because I am not really sure how to begin. That is what I am asking for. I hope I have provided enough info for someone who would know how to do this.

Comment: How do identify the files in the specified directory? Is it all of the files? What would you want to happen if a file doesn't conform to the rules (i.e., 5 whitespace delimited columns each containing an integer). Where would the output file be written?

Comment: Files all have generic names file1.txt, file2.txt etc. Yes, only these generic files in directory. They all conform to rules. As mentioned in title and question, output should be written in new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

numpy is perfect for that kind of treatment:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = [np.loadtxt('%d.txt'%i, dtype=np.int) for i in [1,2,3]]
>>> np.max(data, axis=0)
array([7, 3, 8, 8, 5])
```

Comment: An extension to the question: if there were several files, now each with 3 columns and I wanted to only take the max values from the 3rd column. How could this code be modified?

Comment: `numpy.loadtxt` has an option `usecols` for that purpose: `np.loadtxt(..., usecols=2)` should do the job

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, I would suggest creating a dictionary with 5 entries and for each file, update the maximal number (by the line index)
for example:

```
def get_max_vector():
    all_files = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt"]
    lines_dict = {}
    for i in range(5):
        lines_dict[i] = -1
    for file_name in all_files:
        with open(file_name, "r") as fp:
            i = 0
            for line in fp:
                line = line.replace('\n', '')
                n = int(line)
                lines_dict[i] = max(lines_dict[i], n)
                i += 1
    for i in range(5):
        print(f"max number in line {i} is {lines_dict[i]})
```

this example assumes each file is exactly 5 lines long, each line contains a positive number and that there is at least 1 file. you can add additional checks as you'd like, but this should be a good start for you

Comment: Thanks, however i get an error with the last line: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: probably because an extra sixth line - the program is trying to execute int() on no integer data

Answer (score 0):

This code makes no allowance for non-conforming input files but shows a strategy that you could consider using. It assumes that the relevant input files are in your current working directory and all have a .txt extension. The result will be written into the same directory but using a filename that does **not** have a .txt extension just in case you run it more than once. Assumes Python 3.8+

```
import glob

cols = [0] * 5
for infile in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(infile) as f:
        for i, v in enumerate(f.read().split()):
            if (_v := int(v)) > cols[i]:
                cols[i] = _v
with open('result.res', 'w') as out:
    print(*cols, file=out)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Can it be modified for version 2.6.6?

Comment: Yes you can do that

Comment: what needs to change?

Comment: Try running in 2.6 and you'll find out. SO isn't a homework production line. You need to do some work yourself